# Generate jar for source code using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, fatjar

I'm trying to generate the jar file for the source code of a Gradle project.
I'm using Gradle 6.6.1
I tried

```
task fatJar2(type: Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.main.MainClass'
  }
  archiveClassifier = "all"
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
  with jar
}
```

it's giving me the following error:

```
C:\api_test_restassured_nickt>gradle :fatJar2 > Task :compileJava FAILED ^ Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 100 errors FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. BUILD FAILED in 2s 1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

It's way too long. But it shows a list of packages that all pertain to another repo (framework). The test repo for which i'm trying to build the JAR is dependent on the Framework.

Below is my build.gradle class

```
/*
 * This build file was auto generated by running the Gradle 'init' task
 * at '1/28/16 10:33 AM' with Gradle 2.9
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/2.9/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 8

targetCompatibility = 8



task fatJar(type: Jar) {

    manifest {

        attributes 'tests': 'Gradle Jar'
    }
    
      from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    baseName = project.name

    with jar

}

task fatJar2(type: Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.main.MainClass'
  }
  archiveClassifier = "all"
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
  with jar
}

repositories {

    jcenter()

    mavenCentral()

    flatDir {

       dirs 'libs'

   }

}

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile   
   into 'dependenciesTestRepo'
}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'

    compile group: 'com.jayway.restassured', name: 'rest-assured', version:'2.9.0'
    
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '5.2'

    implementation "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11"

    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11"

    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11"

    implementation "javax.activation:activation:1.1.1" 

}
```

If i Export to Jar File using Eclipse, it works perfectly. So basically, what i need to do is do the Export to JAR functionality that Eclipse has but in Command Line.
Any ideas on how can i generate this jar file?

Comment: It's generally preferred that you show error data as formatted text, rather than as an image (it is easier to read, search, etc). Can you [edit] your question?

Comment: C:\api_test_restassured_nickt>gradle :fatJar2

> Task :compileJava FAILED


                    ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
100 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.




BUILD FAILED in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

Comment: It's way too long. But it shows a list of packages that all pertain to another repo (framework). 
The test repo for which i'm trying to build the JAR is dependent on the Framework.

Comment: If i Export to Jar File using Eclipse, it works perfectly. 
So basically, what i need to do is do the Export to JAR functionality that Eclipse has but in Command Line.

Comment: OK - thank you for the extra info - but it should all be added directly to the question, rather than added as comments. Can you [edit] your question? The more relevant & concise info you can show in the question, the more likely you are to get a helpful response from the community.

Comment: Thanks for your advise Andrew. 
Question edited. 

I hope i get an answer soon.